Как добавлять поля ввода Entry в окно программы
Я создал окно в котором по нажатию кнопки (по задумке) должны вставляться поля Entry. По нажатию кнопки первый раз вставляется дополнительное поле, во второй раз ничего не происходит. Как сделать чтобы каждый раз по нажатию кнопки вставлялось поле Entry?
Вот код:
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import*

class exemple(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.etr = Entry().grid(row=1, column=1)
        self.btn=Button(text='Add', command=self.add).grid(row=1, column=2, padx=10) # Кнопка для вызова функции

    
        

    def add (self):
        entries = []
        count = 1
        rows = 2
        MAX_NUM = 4 # Максимальное количество записей
        if count <= MAX_NUM:
            entries.append(Entry(self)) # Создать и добавить в список
            entries[-1].grid(row=rows,column=count,padx=10) # Разместите только что созданный виджет
            count += 1 # Увеличьте количество на 1
            
            

        

        self.mainloop()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    ex = exemple()


Почему у вас вызов mainloop внутри обработчика кнопки? Он должен запускаться один раз после создания окна, в данном случае внутри __init__ или в блоке if __name__ == "__main__":

По вашей проблеме: у вас count - это локальная переменная метода add. При каждом входе в метод add она заново становится 1, и при выходе из метода забывается, потому что она локальная. В итоге у вас все новые объекты Entry создаются в одной и той же ячейке.

insolor Если я выношу count за add, выдает ошибку: UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable 'count' where it is not associated with a value

Сделайте count полем объекта. В __init__ ее инициализируйте, в add используйте и увеличивайте после создания объекта.

@insolor. Спасибо, очень выручили!
